# What was the actual "commitment" we all made?

Tags: support

I remember it being specific, like providing a certain number of answers during the beta. (I'm being serious here.)

In Area51 is says, currently, 0% of us have fulfilled our commitment. (That's fine, stack just launched.) But I was thinking I should figure out what exactly I committed to doing...

But, I can't find the commitment specifics on Area51 any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anna Lear commented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118430): 10 questions/answers and three months of participation are required.

While this is a bit technically, and can be changed over time, I especially like Robert's [explanation on area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4008): Committing to a site means you agree to use the site and help build it.

Comment: Minor correction below.

Answer (score 2):

Technical commitment: Ten questions/answers, particularly in private beta.  Commitments *expire* after three months of beta so after 3 months if you didn't ask or answer ten questions you can no longer fulfil your commitment.  This answer is based on having been through more than one beta in the past.

Note that commitments cannot be deemed filled until after the site has been in public beta for about a day.  Sites that fail in private beta (I don't think us!) will never register fulfilled commitments.

Community commitment: As Stephan says, it is about building the site.  This is more open-ended.  After the site goes public, it's easier for people who want out to just leave and we can hope that new people come in to fill the ranks and help make the site better.